# How to disable specific options in a select in Groovy Server Pages (gsp)

Tags: select, groovy, drop-down-menu, gsp

I have the below select tag in my gsp which is working fine.

```
<q:select id="myItem" 
      name="myItem" 
      from="${items}" 
      optionKey="id" 
      value="${item?.id}"
      optionValue="${{it?.name)}}"
      noSelection="${['': '']}" />
```

But I need to disable couple of options within the select based on its status attribute.

```
items = [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'test',
          status: 'available'
         },
         {
          id: 2,
          name: 'john',
          status: 'booked'
         },
         {
          id: 3,
          name: 'sans',
          status: 'available'
         }];
```

I want the option item with status `booked` to be shown as readonly or disabled. How to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add an `optionDisabled` attribute like:

```
optionDisabled="${{it?.status == 'booked'}}
```

to your `<g:select>`.

EDIT: for anyone coming to this later, note @HansMaulwurf comment below noting that you'll need to use `optionKey` as well.

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. Is there any documentation for this.

Comment: Not that I can find.  Utils grails 3.1.1, tags were documented in the standard documentation but now that is gone.  Even in 3.1.1 not all options were documented, including this one.  Best approach I have found is to look through the source.

Comment: Looks like you cannot combine `selected` and `disabled` <option> parameters

Comment: I don't think this is actually suggesting to combine those.  Then again, I don't remember how `optionDisabled` worked.

Comment: Make sure you use `optionKey` since it will not work without it: https://github.com/grails/grails-gsp/blob/master/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/grails/plugins/web/taglib/FormTagLib.groovy#L992